# How do I remove the logo from this template frontage?

Tags: graphics

I'm not able to locate where the frontpage logo has been inserted in the code of the following template: https://da.overleaf.com/latex/templates/kom-thesis-template-v1-dot-5-1/tsmshxkgpyjy

How can I remove this logo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It forms part of the report title style (in `report/tudreprt_title.sty`) which places the logo. The logo itself is defined inside `base/tudpaper.sty` with the following definition:

```
\newcommand{\TUD@includelogo}{%
  \colorbox{white}{%
    \includegraphics[%
      viewport=0 0 135.79 63,
      height=\TUD@logo@height,clip
    ]{tud_logo}%
    \hspace*{10pt}%
  }\hspace*{-10pt}%
}%
```

One option would be to replace the current logo `tud_logo.pdf`/`.eps` (in the `logo` folder) with a blank version of an image, or place a new version of your own logo in there.

You can also update `\TUD@includelogo` directly within your preamble to insert a blank box of prespecified width/height:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\TUD@includelogo{%
  \rule{20em}{0pt}% Box width
  \rule{0pt}{5em}% Box height
}
\makeatother
```

You need some height to this blank box to allow the formatting of the rest of the title to work.

[image]